# Psql only select rows with valid geometry

Tags: sql, postgresql, error-handling, geometry

I want to calculate the length of all the geometries in the table **dataset_object**.

```
select 
     st_length(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 2)), split_part(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 1), '='::text, 2)::integer))::text AS lengte,
     st_isvalid(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 2)), split_part(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 1), '='::text, 2)::integer)),
    (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text as shape
FROM dataset_object
WHERE dataset_object.object_type::text = 'Waterkering'::text 
and st_isvalid(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 2)), split_part(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 1), '='::text, 2)::integer)) is True
```

This results in the following table:

```
Lengte      st_isvalid  shape
11.66819931 true        SRID=28992;LINESTRING Z(242724.282699998 570218.723099999 …
142.3694493 true        SRID=28992;LINESTRING Z(235640.405999999 580624.9628 …
12.14911526 true        SRID=28992;LINESTRING Z(242698.064100001 570181.706900001 …
```

Now if I fetch to many rows this error is returned:

> SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry   Hint: ""
> <-- parse error at position 1 within geometry

To fix this I was hoping to only select the rows where **st_invalid** is true:

> and
> st_isvalid(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext(split_part((dataset_object.data
> -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 2)), split_part(split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering'::text) ->>
> 'shape'::text, ';'::text, 1), '='::text, 2)::integer)) is not null

But this doesn't help either.

Can anyone explain what the error means, where it comes from and how I should proceed?

I think it happens when the **st_geomfromtext** command is run.

Comment: Is it possible that some `dataset_object`'s don't have anything in the `"shape"` field? In that case it breaks when `st_geomfromtext()` gets an empty string in your `where` section. You can get this error if you try just `select st_geomfromtext('');`

Comment: Perhaps use a `WHERE` condition to filter out empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dirty trick for skipping problematic geometries:

```sql
create function ST_TryGeomFromText(arg text) 
returns geometry language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return st_geomfromtext(arg);
exception
    when others then return null;
end $$;
```

You can wrap any PostGIS *ST_* function this way, or just any function parsing your inputs. But the problem will remain that some of your `dataset_object`'s don't have the geometry text you expect in their `shape` field.

```sql
with 
 dataset_object(object_type,data) as ( 
 values 
    ('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{"shape":"SRID=12;LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,3 4)"}}'::jsonb),
    --('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{"shape":"SRID=12;LINESTRING()"}}'::jsonb),
    ('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{"shape":"SRID=12;"}}'::jsonb),
    ('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{"shape":"SRID=12"}}'::jsonb),
    ('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{"shape":""}}'::jsonb),
    ('Waterkering','{"Waterkering":{}}'::jsonb) )
,parsed_dataset_objects as (
    select 
        object_type,
        data,
        (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering')             as waterkering,
        (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape' as waterkering_shape, 
        split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape',';', 2) 
                                            as waterkering_shape_field_1,
        split_part(split_part((dataset_object.data->'Waterkering')->>'shape',';',1),'=',2)
                                            as waterkering_shape_field_1_equals,
        split_part((dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape',';', 2)                         
                                            as waterkering_shape_field_2
    from dataset_object)
select concat('ST_GeomFromText(''',waterkering_shape_field_2,''')') as "call" 
from parsed_dataset_objects;
```

Results of the query above show you how your extraction method can fail to provide arguments for `ST_GeomFromText()`, which causes the parse error you're getting:

```
                    call
--------------------------------------------
 ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,1 1,3 4)')
 ST_GeomFromText('')--throws an error
 ST_GeomFromText('')--throws an error
 ST_GeomFromText('')--throws an error
 ST_GeomFromText('')--throws an error
(5 rows)
```

You can make your `where` conditions more detailed and also save some space and copy-pasting thanks to [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)'s:

```sql
with 
 parsed_dataset_objects as (
    select 
        object_type,
        data,
        (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') as waterkering,
        (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape' as waterkering_shape, 
        split_part(
            (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape',
            ';', 2) as waterkering_shape_field_1,
        split_part(
            split_part(
                (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape',
                ';', 1), 
            '=', 2
        ) as waterkering_shape_field_1_equals,
        split_part(
            (dataset_object.data -> 'Waterkering') ->> 'shape',
            ';', 2) as waterkering_shape_field_2
    from dataset_object)
,geoms as (
    select st_setsrid(
                st_geomfromtext(waterkering_shape_field_2),
                waterkering_shape_field_1_equals::integer) as geom
    from parsed_dataset_objects
    where object_type::text = 'Waterkering'::text
    and coalesce(waterkering_shape_field_2,'')<>''
    and coalesce(waterkering_shape_field_1_equals,'')<>'')
select 
    st_length(geom)::text AS lengte,
    st_isvalid(geom),
    st_astext(geom) as shape
FROM geoms;
```

But my advice is to trace the records that cause the problem and fix them at the source. There are way too many ways your incoming `text`/`json` can be invalid and handling that in `where` is a temporary fix.